# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I want to save a collection in firebase name like when a use like a post I want to save it into the firebase firestore

Comment: Have you initialized the DB? Can you `console.log(id, session.user.uid)` right before setDoc and share the output?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: when I console.log it is showing undefined

Comment: id is correct just the sesson.user.uid

Comment: It looks like you are not initializing DB. Can you share complete code.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this imported?

```
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
```

Should the code look like this later? ; ) I follow the same tutorial. I was having problems with it too. I don't know how I solved this problem. Try my solution first. If that doesn't work, I can send you some extra stuff (that might have solved it).

```
const likePost = async () => {
    if (hasLiked) {
        await deleteDoc(doc(db, "posts", id, "likes", session.user.uid));
    } else {
        await setDoc(doc(db, "posts", id, "likes", session.user.uid), {
            username: session.user.username,
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const likePost = async () => {     
        await setDoc(doc(db, 'posts', id, 'likes', id), {
            username: session.user.name,
        })
    };
```

because de seesion.user.uid is undefined, i use id and its work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).